# New column MAX(update_at) form 2 joined tables

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have 2 tables:

```
subscribers
    - id
    - updated_at
payments
    - id
    - subscriber_id
    - updated_at
```

```
$query->leftJoin(
    $this->paymentsTable,
    "$this->paymentsTable.subscriber_id",
    "=",
    "$this->subscribersTable.id"
);
```

I want to select new column *last_update*, which are `MAX(updated_at)` from 2 joined tables eg.

Subscribers:

| id | updated_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 2020-02-02 |

Payments:

| id | subscriber_id | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-03-03 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-02-02 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-02-02 |

Expected Output:

- last_update for subscriber1 = 2022-02-02
- last_update for subscriber2 = 2021-02-02

How to write such a query?

Comment: Do you want the query or the ORM implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Subscriber Model, you may add a new [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) as:

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Payment;

class Subscriber
{
    public function getLastUpdateAttribute()
    {
        $payment = $this->payments()->orderByDesc('updated_at')->first();

        return optional($payment)->updated_at;
    }

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }
}
```